# Over contributed to Dependent Care FSA for 2014

Tags: united-states, excess-contribution, fsa

My husband and I just realized that we both contributed to our employer's Dependent Care FSA for 2014. He put in the maximum allowed $5,000 and I put in $3,600 for a total of $8,600.  Unfortunately, we realized this after our benefits deadline for for 2014. We are worried that we will lose the excess $3,600 contributed.  I have read in older posts that we should claim all of the $8,600 thru FSA and add the $3,600 to our gross income W2 claims for 2014.  This would avoid any penalty.  Is this correct or will we lose the $3,600?
Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you'll be able to get the money by submitting legitimate receipts for care for your child, and at tax time you'll pay the tax on the extra $3600.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if there will be any penalty other then paying the taxes on the $3,600?  I was so worried we'd be out the entire excess amount.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, DCA may be taken out of income pre-FICA as well as pre income tax. If that's right, the tax return will add that back in, so an extra 7.5%. No penalty, just the tracking and submitting to get your money back.